# Función Filter, ¿Cómo es que funciona?

Tags: javascript, funciones, filtro

soy nuevo en JavaScript y estoy tratando de entender la lógica de este. viendo un ejemplo del uso de la clase filter para Arrays no logro comprender lo siguiente:

si

```
console.log(15  %   3   === 0);
```

me retorna un booleano, en este caso true. ¿por que

```
var miArray =   [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]; 
var resultado   =   miArray.filter(function(elemento) {
  return    elemento    %   3   === 0;
});
```

me retorna un array [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]?,
No debería de retornarme un array de booleanos, ya que la expresión elemento    %   3   === 0 retorna un booleano?

Muchas gracias al que pueda explicarme esto :D

Comment: He rechazado tu edit a mi respuesta. He puesto `.map` a propósito para que veas como funciona en el snippet

Comment: He cometido un error, hay forma de eliminar esa edición?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como puedes ver en [esta documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), el método filtre lo que hace es como su nombre lo indica, filtrar los datos a través de un `callback`, en tu caso el callback es `elemento % 3 === 0`, esto quiere decir que todos los números que divididos entre 3 su residuo sea 0 en el callback serán `true` y por lo tanto los regresará

Si lo que quieres es un array de boleados que cumplan la función, tal vez debas intentar con [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

```
var miArray =   [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]; 
var resultado   =   miArray.map(function(elemento) {
   return    elemento    %   3   === 0;
});
```

Esta función iterará sobre todos los elementos y regresará cada elemento modificado por el callback, por lo que tendrás como resultado

```
[false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true]
```

Comment: Claro!, estaba confundiendo su funcionamiento con el de map, por eso no podía entender. pero que es un callback?

Answer (score 2):

> Devuelve: Un nuevo array con los elementos que cumplen la condición. Si ningún
>   elemento cumple la condición, se devolverá un array vacío.

[Valor devuelto del método .filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter#Valor_devuelto)

El nombre de la propia función lo dice "filter", lo que hace es filtrar en un conjunto de valores para ver cuales cumplen ese "filtro".

---

Para tu ejemplo lo que buscarías sería usar el método [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

> El método map() crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a
>   la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

```js
var miArray =   [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]; 
var resultado   =   miArray.map(function(elemento) {
  return    elemento    %   3   === 0;
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: he cometido un error hay forma de eliminar esta edición?

Comment: @StivenTrujillo La he rechazado por lo cual no se aplicará. No te preocupes.